# Fb/Instagram Graph API: (#10) permission denied on business_discovery

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I'm trying to run the following:

```
<my_insta_fbid>?fields=business_discovery.username(<business_page>)
```

on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

But I'm getting an **error (#10) permission denied**

- My app is approved for instagram_basic, User Token also includes it
- Business verification is passed too
- I have Instagram Graph API and Instagram Basic Display products included
- Instagram account is connected to my fb that generates user token(but created separately)
- Insta account I use is included into Instagram Basic Display
- Of course, I use and request instagram business accounts
- I tried both Live and Development app modes
- All the other requests related to <my_insta_fbid> like *name* or *biography* work. The only that fails is *business_discovery*

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it!

My tests have shown that I was missing the **instagram_manage_insights** permission.

I didn't find any mentions of this in the documentation but it worked in my case